# How to fix Travis-CI [Composer\Exception\NoSslException] with PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

I have a project that I'm [building and testing on travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/admonkey/PrioritizationMatrix) for 3 primary PHP environments that I deploy into (7.0, 5.5.9, and 5.3.3).

This [builds and tests perfectly fine in 7.0.8](https://travis-ci.org/admonkey/PrioritizationMatrix/jobs/145440545) and [5.5.9](https://travis-ci.org/admonkey/PrioritizationMatrix/jobs/145440546), but for [5.3.3 I get this error](https://travis-ci.org/admonkey/PrioritizationMatrix/jobs/145440547):

> ```
>   [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]                                          
>   The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not availab  
>   le. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error  
>   , at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
> ```

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35466008/4233593) and the obvious advice of the error message that there's a workaround, but I really don't want to extend that insecurity to the rest of my environments.

At first I thought composer must require a higher version of PHP to work correctly, but [according to their `composer.json`, they only require 5.3.2](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/composer.json#L25)

Then I notice when adding `php -i` to my install script that it's not compiled in the environment with the `configure` script, but it is compiled in the newer environments.

In 7.0:

> ```
> Configure Command =>  './configure'
> ...
> '--with-openssl'
> ...
> Phar
> ...
> Native OpenSSL support => enabled
> ```

In 5.3.3:

> ```
> Phar
> ...
> OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)
> ```

I see from [their cookbook](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Installing-additional-PHP-extensions) that you can install PECL extensions, but [I don't think the openssl extension is available through PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package-search.php?pkg_name=openssl&pkg_maintainer=&pkg_category=&released_on_year=&released_on_month=&released_on_day=&released_before_year=&released_before_month=&released_before_day=&released_since_year=&released_since_month=&released_since_day=).

How do I get this working?